# Wrapfig with sidecaption (floatrow) - How to get text wrapped around a sidecaption and image?

Tags: floats, wrapfigure, floatrow, sidecap

I'm writing my PhD thesis, and for my experimental setup page, I want to put a page-long image of my cryogenic insert. It's a figure with length of `\textheight` and width of approximately `0.1\textwidth`. For the caption, I'd like to use `sidecap`, since my figure is too long and narrow for the caption to fit underneath it. However, if I just use `\fcapside` from the `floatrow` package, it will stretch out the caption to fit the entire text height, having only one word on each line and looking very ugly.

My idea is to let the picture span the entire height of the page, and to have the caption be a small box on the side containing the description, all the text wrapping around.

How do I do such a thing?

Here is a picture of roughly what I want:

[image]

Comment: I would put the side image using minpages, and use wrapfig only for the caption.  The only problem here is whether you have paragraphs breaking at the beginning and end of the page.

Comment: I tried to do this using minipages, but this shifted the figure to the following two pages, messing up everything with it. Furthermore, I do have these paragraphs breaking here.

Comment: Recently `CTAN` released a package `wrapstuff`, hope this will helps you...

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution using `geometry` and `marginpar`. I redefined the `textwidth` and `marginparwidth`. I then added the figure in a `\marginpar` environment and used a `wrapfig` environment for the caption.

```
\newgeometry{textwidth=10cm,marginparwidth=45pt}
\subsection{Remote operation and automation}

\marginpar{
        \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{cutout.png}
}

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{.4\textwidth}
    \caption{Picture of the low noise insert used in this research.}
    \label{fig:insertpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

The only thing I didn't get right was to end the `\newgeometry` after the current page by using `\afterpage{\restoregeometry}`. I found some questions about it, and decided to just leave that alone. I now `\restoregeometry` after the section and use the extra space to add an extra picture.

Comment: I would give a +1 if this were testable.  Like an MWE, it should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The problem with `\afterpage{\restoregeometry}` is that `\aftergroup` runs in a TeX group. And `\restoregeometry` makes local changes (which I find suboptimal). Usually the following works: `\afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}` although this would fail if the page break is inside a group. But even then there is the problem that a paragraph that crosses the page boundary has been typeset with the width of the first page. So usually the first part of the next page will have the wrong width. Only the next paragraph or so will have the restored text width.